# Overwriting phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, centos5

I am using Centos 5.5 and had phpMyAdmin version 2.11.11 installed. I couldn't find a way to update it, so what I did was do a manual download, backed up /usr/share/phpmyadmin, then replaced that folder with the new install.

Everything seems to work, but I wanted to know if there is any issues with doing it this way? And if so, what would be the best way of doing the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any issue at all doing it this way, but if you had it installed as an RPM package please be aware that if by some reason yum decides to try to update this package it'll overwrite your current install.

To try to check for that you can try the following

- See if phpmyadmin belongs to any current rpm packages
  `rpm -qf /usr/share/phpmyadmin/anyfilethere`
- If it does belong to an RPM package just remove the package without removing the contents
  `rpm -e --justdb [packagename]`

That'll make sure you don't have any kind of accidents in the future

Comment: Thanks!  It was part of an RPM package and that line worked perfectly!